# Close Save As window without saving

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to save a Word document according to this condition:

```
IF 'check something' Then:
    Dim myDialog As Object
    Set myDialog = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    myDialog.Display
    myDialog.Execute
End if

Continue doing all the rest...
```

If the Save As window opens and the user closes it without saving by clicking the (X) on the upper corner the sub continues to run as if the user decides to save the file.

How can I exit the sub if the user closes the Save As window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have used Excel VBA, but you can easily change it for Word.

```
Sub Test()
    myDialog = False
    myDialog = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
    If myDialog = False Then
        MsgBox "Don't Execute"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Execute Stuff"
    End If

    MsgBox "After If Condition"
End Sub
```